# Don't block us for running IP xrefs!

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, ip-address

Whenever one uses the IP xref tool, one request per IP is made to the server. This means, whenever investigating a user with too many IPs, I hit the ratelimit. This means two things:

1. I get temporarily blocked.

   [image]
2. The information that said request is supposed to fetch is never fetched for the last IPs, leading to  a bunch of loading icons. Frankly speaking, the info that the request fetches isn't that important.

   [image]

   [image]

Could those requests be batched up or something?

Comment: I don't think that's the right link... in there I'm referring to something quite different.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: huh, fixed.

Comment: Ironic that I got the error while trying to view this very question ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with the next build we'll pause a bit while fetching lots of ips.  This should prevent per-ip flood throttling.

Unfortunately, the queries that back that tool are really quite expensive (which is why they're run on demand, over small time windows); running them in a batch isn't really practical, we need to space them out.

Comment: Just a note: This still happens at times, though with _much_ less frequency (I had to xref myself and wait a minute-ish for it to happen). It's good enough, though :)